# How to add smooth animation to remove one of the element from Row with transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I need to display a text along with logo when sidebar is open and need to remove the name when sidebar is closed with animation.

My react component rendering looks like this

```
<Row style={{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    flexWrap: 'nowrap'
}}>
    <img src={Logo} width={32} />
    <span
        style={{
            fontFamily: 'Overpass',
            fontSize: 'x-large',
            fontWeight: '600',
            width: open ? 'auto' : '0px',
            transition: 'opacity 1s ease-in-out, width 1s ease-in-out, visibility 0.7s ease-in-out',
            opacity: open ? '1' : '0',
            visibility: open ? 'visible' : 'hidden',
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
        }}>
        Rigel
    </span>
</Row>
```

But this is creating jerky animation, when animation starts the logo and text position is changed and even after collapse logo is not centered in the row.

Please refer this gif

[image]

Seems because it is not gone out of the DOM but just hidden. If I set `display: none` then logo is centered but then I can't apply the transition.

What is a better way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using

```
<Row
    style={{
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        overflow: 'hidden',
    }}
>
    <Row
        style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            flexWrap: 'nowrap',
            width: open ? '100%' : '32px',
            transition: 'width 1s ease-in-out',
        }}
    >
        <img src={Logo} width={32} />
        <span
            style={{
                fontFamily: 'Overpass',
                fontSize: 'x-large',
                fontWeight: '600',
                marginLeft: open ? '10px' : '0px',
                transition: 'opacity 1s ease-in-out, margin-left 0.7s ease-in-out',
                opacity: open ? '1' : '0',
                overflow: 'hidden',
            }}
        >
            Rigel
        </span>
    </Row>
</Row>
```